What does the error message " & ex.Message) mean in a Visual Basic .NET 8 project?
I have a .NET 8 project written in Visual Basic in the process of being upgraded from .NET Framework 4.8. I have just used the upgrade assistant extension in VS 2022. It was able to complete, but I am now getting these two error messages when I try to build it: " & ex.Message) and " & Ex.Message). The file listed for causing the error in VS 2022 is just "VBC" and it doesn't link to any file.
I am very new to Visual Studio, Visual Basic, and .NET, so any clarification as to what these error messages mean would be appreciated. Due to the cryptic nature of the error message and the symbols involved I have not been able to find any information about it through google or forums.

Have you searched your project for those exact strings?  The error might jump out at you.

Are you saying that " & ex.Message) is the only information there is about the error? How does it look like in Visual Studio?

The following may be of interest: How to: Break and Combine Statements in Code (Visual Basic) and Line continuation character '_' must be preceded by at least one white space and must be the last character on the line

This question looks very much like this recent question: VBC Error '& e_emb.Message Visual Studio 22 Preview.

Based on the linked duplicate, it looks to me like there is a compiler bug.  I believe there are a couple of potential workarounds in the link.

Thanks to @TnTinMn, @Craig, and @JiachenLi, I was able to find a solution. This post is indeed the same problem: VBC Error '& e_emb.Message Visual Studio 22 Preview
I solved my issue by just moving the contents of a MessageBox.Show that had string concatenation operators outside of the function call.
Causes the error:
MessageBox.Show("Cannot write file to disk. Original error: " & ex.Message)
Does not cause the error:
Dim exMsg = "Cannot write file to disk. Original error: " & ex.Message
MessageBox.Show(exMsg)

You may consider trying String Interpolation.

Due to the problem that arises from the . After the .NET Framework project is upgraded to the .NET project, there is a high probability that the error will be validate platform compatibility.
Does your code involve the ex.Message error message output using MessageBox.Show?
Try removing this section to see if the issue is resolved.
